# Ubuntu 14.04 won't power off after I run update-rc.d ccpd defaults 99

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I followed installation procedure of Canon LBP2900 printer on ask Ubuntu thread. At the end printer started working. All is well till I run update-rc.d ccpd defaults 99 in terminal. My computer won't power off it log outs and hangs at Ubuntu logo (with blue,pink red or green background). How can I revert it back or solve the power off reboot problem.

Answer (score 0):

The hanging of UBUNTU at shutdown (or reboot) is caused by the script /etc/init.d/ccdp. The first if-statement looks for a running cups. But in case of shutdown cups is already terminated and the if-statement will never succeed!
Move this statement in the start section or use the slightly modified Script from Radu Cotescu for UBUNTU instead. (https://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/). In my case it works fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
# startup script for Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS (ccpd)
# Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Radu Cotescu
# Slightly modified for UBUNTU with Upstart by Gerhard Kraus
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       ccpd
# Required-Start: 
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   1
# Short-Description: Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS
### END INIT INFO

DAEMON=/usr/sbin/ccpd
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/subsys/ccpd
NAME=ccpd
DESC="Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS"

test -f $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin

ccpd_start ()
{
    if [ `ps awx | grep cupsd | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ]; then
        while [ `ps awx | grep cupsd | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ]
        do
            sleep 3
        done
        sleep 5
    fi

    log_begin_msg "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec ${DAEMON}
    log_end_msg $?
}

ccpd_stop ()
{
    log_begin_msg "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --signal 15 --exec ${DAEMON}
    log_end_msg $?
}


case $1 in

    start)    
        ccpd_start
        ;;

    stop)
        ccpd_stop
        ;;

    status)
        echo "$DESC: $NAME:" `pidof $NAME`
        ;;

    restart)
        log_begin_msg "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
        ccpd_stop
        sleep 2
        ccpd_start
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: ccpd {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```